# How to simulate Listview scrollability and pixel overflow control using the column widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-column

I'm trying to use `Spacer()` within the children of Listview, but it's not working the way it should. So I changed to column, as the `Spacer()` works fine in it. However I can't come to a implementation that simulates the responsivity and pixel overflow control as the Listview using column. Is there a better way to do this?

Code with list view:

```
return Drawer(
  backgroundColor: CustomColours.vertraIce,
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: [
      DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: CustomColours.vertraBlue,
        ),
        child: const Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.webp'),
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
        title: Text(
          'Perfil ',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          await Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/');
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.receipt_long),
        title: Text(
          'Notas',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          await Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/receipt');
        },
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      const Divider(),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.info_outlined),
        title: Text(
          'Sobre nós',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          _launchURL();
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
        title: Text(
          'Sair',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          authFirebase.signOut();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

### code with Column:

```
return Drawer(
  backgroundColor: CustomColours.vertraIce,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: CustomColours.vertraBlue,
        ),
        child: const Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.webp'),
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
        title: Text(
          'Perfil ',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          await Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/');
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.receipt_long),
        title: Text(
          'Notas',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          await Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/receipt');
        },
      ),
      const Spacer(),
      const Divider(),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.info_outlined),
        title: Text(
          'Sobre nós',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          _launchURL();
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
        title: Text(
          'Sair',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: CustomColours.vertraBlack,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          authFirebase.signOut();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone still looking for the answer to my question, I solved it and here it is:

You simply wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` and put it as a child of a `Column`. Then the `ListTile` you want to be at the bottom has to be put was a child of `Column`. As seen in the code below:

```
class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Item $index'),
              onTap: () {
                // Do something when the ListTile is tapped
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Bottom ListTile'),
        // Add your logic or functionality here
      ),
    ],
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make space between an object and another (and you don't like spacer) you can wrap the tile into a `Padding()` widget and set the padding parameter to `EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10)`. You can also set padding for left, top or right.

```
Padding(
 padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10),
 child: //your tile
);
```

You can use this solution in `column`, `listView` or where you want.

Edit:
If you don't want to use spacer and you need that your object goes bottom, you can use `Align` widget in order to do that.

```
Expanded(
  child: Align(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          child: //Your widget here,
    ),
  ),
),
```

This should work.
Using spacer by the way is good i think.

Comment: That's a good solution, but I wanted something that takes all the available space between certain tiles. Setting it statically would solve the problem only for the device I'm using to debug.

Comment: Check my edit if it works for you

Comment: Unfortunately that's also not working for me :(